# Some more questions on merging which I do not understand

Tags: svn, merge

I have been tasked with merging two SVN branches.  Basically, we had one only (Trunk or head).  They made a branch a while ago called Phase 4 which they now want integrated back into the trunk.  I have read some documentation but am still confused on a few things (and this is with Eclipse).

First, does the merging back get done completely within the subversion repositories?  I didn't think so but wasn't sure.

If not, do I check out the Trunk or the Phase 4 into my directory, or do I check them both out into my directory?  Then you click on your working directory and select team->merge for the URL in the "reintegrate" box do you then choose the trunk or do you choose the "phase 4" one?

I am still a bit confused.  Then if it puts them side-by-side is the runk on the left or the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, we had one only (Trunk or head).

Do you really call trunk *"head"*? HEAD in Subversion is a [revision keyword](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.keywords) that stands for latest / youngest revision in repository.

> They made a branch a while ago called Phase 4 which they now want
>   integrated back into the trunk. I have read some documentation but am
>   still confused on a few things

[Reintegrate merges](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.reintegrate) are automatic with SVN 1.8 and newer clients. You don't need to add `--reintegrate` option with up-to-date SVN client. So if there are no hidden issues, you could complete the task in three or four steps:

1. Obtain a fresh working copy of /trunk: `svn checkout URL-TRUNK`
2. Merge the WC with the branch: `svn merge ^^/path-to-branch`
3. REVIEW THE RESULT OF MERGE and resolve conflicts if there are any.
4. Commit the result of merge: `svn commit -m "COMMIT LOG MESSAGE`

> (and this is with Eclipse).

Use `svn` command line client and [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/) if you are on Windows.

I would personally recommend that you avoid running any advanced version-control operations within Eclipse. Most trivial version-control operations such as checkout / commit / update in SVN or clone / checkout / push in Git work from Eclipse. But when it comes to anything more complex than that, Eclipse VCS UI becomes very confusing.

> First, does the merging back get done completely within the subversion
>   repositories? I didn't think so but wasn't sure.

No, you always perform merge operations in your local [working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.working-copy).

Before you begin, you *have* to read [SVNBook | Branching and Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.html). You could also try merges with some test project. If you are not familiar with SVN, read these chapters, too:

- [SVNBook | Fundamental Concepts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.html)
- [SVNBook | Basic Usage](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.html)
- [SVNBook | Resolve Any Conflicts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve)

And don't miss TortoiseSVN Manual that's a must-read of TortoiseSVN and SVN users on Windows:

- [TortoiseSVN Manual | Basic Version-Control Concepts](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-basics.html)
- [TortoiseSVN Manual | Branching / Tagging](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html)
- [TortoiseSVN Manual | Merging](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html)
- [TortoiseSVN Manual | Resolving Conflicts](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html)

Comment: About "Head" no maybe not.  I was probably confused.  Been using SVN but have never merged before